# Capping function returns error about missing values and NaN's?

Tags: r, na, outliers, quantile

I am attempting to use the following function in order to cap some outliers so that my dataset is tidy:

```
cap <- function(x){
    quantiles <- quantile(x, c(.05, 0.25, 0.75, .95))
    x[x < quantiles[2] - 1.5*IQR(x)] <- quantiles[1]
    x[x > quantiles[3] + 1.5*IQR(x)] <- quantiles[4]
    x
}
```

However, it seems that every time I attempt to use it, I receive the following error:

> "Error in quantile.default(x, c(0.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95)) :    missing
>   values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE"

The dataset I am using does have missing values in it, and I would like disregard them in order to perform this function. I have tried plugging `na.rm = TRUE` into particular parts of the function itself and can't seem to arrive at any outcome that isn't the error message above.

Comment: where have you tried adding the na.rm=T?

Comment: Do you also need na.rm = T in your IQR functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `na.rm = T` inside `quantile` and `IQR` should solve your problem:

```
cap <- function(x){
  quantiles <- quantile(x, c(.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95), na.rm = T)
  x[x < quantiles[2] - 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = T)] <- quantiles[1]
  x[x > quantiles[3] + 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = T)] <- quantiles[4]
  return(x)
}
```

Here is some testdata: I added two outliers at the end (10 and -20) as well as one NA.
The two outliers are replaced, NA is not:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- c(rnorm(100), 10, -20, NA_real_)
cap(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This ended up working perfectly, I had been trying na.rm = T in one part of the function at a time and not in simultaneous spots.